# Calculation of date in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

```
   1      28/11/2011 ...
```

How do I write a function in SQL to implement the above pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @BaseDate DATE = '20111107';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = GETDATE(); --Or the "end of dates in the database"
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS [Counter],
        @BaseDate AS [MyDate]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [Counter] + 1,
        DATEADD(DAY, 7, MyDate)
    FROM
        RecursiveCTE
    WHERE
        MyDate < @EndDate)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

To handle dates that aren't exact and make this into a function you would do this:

```
--Function definition
CREATE FUNCTION SuperDuperDataCalculator (
    @BaseDate DATE = '20131016',
    @EndDate DATE = '20131020')
RETURNS @Results TABLE (
    [Counter] INT,
    [Date] DATE)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
        SELECT
            1 AS [Counter],
            @BaseDate AS [MyDate]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [Counter] + 1,
            CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 7, MyDate) > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7, MyDate) END
        FROM
            RecursiveCTE
        WHERE
            MyDate < @EndDate)
    INSERT INTO
        @Results
    SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
    RETURN;
END;
GO

--Usage
SELECT * FROM SuperDuperDataCalculator('20131016', '20131020');

--Results
Counter Date
1   2013-10-16
2   2013-10-20
```

Note that we have to use a multi-statement table-valued function as there is a bug in SQL Server where it won't let you use OPTIONs in a simple table-valued function.  The alternative would be to remove the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) from the function and remember to use this every time you reference it (i.e. a pretty poor alternative).

...and finally, if you wanted to just return the maximum counter value you could rewrite this as a scalar-valued function, i.e.:

```
--Function definition
CREATE FUNCTION SuperDuperDataCalculator (
    @BaseDate DATE = '20131016',
    @EndDate DATE = '20131020')
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    [Counter] INT,
    [Date] DATE);
    DECLARE @ReturnValue INT;
    WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
        SELECT
            1 AS [Counter],
            @BaseDate AS [MyDate]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            [Counter] + 1,
            CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 7, MyDate) > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7, MyDate) END
        FROM
            RecursiveCTE
        WHERE
            MyDate < @EndDate)
    INSERT INTO
        @Results
    SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
    SELECT @ReturnValue = MAX([Counter]) FROM @Results;
    RETURN @ReturnValue;
END;
GO
SELECT dbo.SuperDuperDataCalculator('20131016', '20131020');
```

Comment: if the EndDate is lets say 20/10/2013 and my BaseDate(after RecursiveCTE is called ) is 16/10/2013 then the function should stop after taking into account of 20/10/2013.it should not add 7 to 16/10/2013.do i need to check the interval between dates too

Comment: I added a new script that covers this

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it should add 4 to 16/10/2013 it must taken into account all dates in the database in this case it is 20/10/2013. I need a function so that i can use the function name in sql query written in visual studio c#.I am not sure but i guess in SQL we need to write CREATE FUNCTION Funtionname to declare a function

Comment: To create a function it is pretty much what you said, but note the comment I have added about how this is a bit of a pain in SQL Server due to a long-standing bug.  I have updated my answer to show how to create a function AND cope with the new requirement to include the end date regardless.

Comment: thanks its working perfectly fine but i need to return counter only.when first interval of 7 days is calculated the counter should be 1 next 7 days counter should be 2,next 7 days counter should be 3 so on and so forth. i don't want to return the whole table

Comment: If you mean that all you want the function to return is the maximum counter value then you would need to rewrite this as a scalar-valued function and return    SELECT @ReturnValue = MAX([Counter]) FROM @Results;    as the answer?

Comment: ...or you could issue SELECT MAX([Counter]) FROM MyDateUDF(<date>, <date>); from your .NET code?

Comment: when i ran the function in my .netcode in sql query as dbo.SuperDuperDataCalculator(<date>, <date>).it is giving me error....                      Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

Comment: Dude, you need to replace the <date> with the dates you want to send, e.g. SELECT MAX([Counter]) FROM MyDateUDF('20140101', '20140130'); I just put <date> as a placeholder as I thought you would parameterise this bit.  I thought this would be obvious? :P

Comment: kindly see this link on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534290/addition-of-date-in-sql-function this is what i am trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - It will get all the weeks and assign a rownumber in the subquery. Then only select the records where row number = 1 because there might be more results for that week.  So hence RowNo = 1

```
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowNo) AS IncrementalWeek,dte
 FROM 
 (
      SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(ww,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),createdDate,111)) AS [week],
                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),createdDate,111) AS dte,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(ww,Convert(VARCHAR(20),createdDate,111)) ORDER BY DATEPART(ww,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),createdDate,111))) AS RowNo 
      FROM YourTable

 ) AS tble
WHERE RowNo = 1
ORDER BY [week]
```